# Multiarch 20.04 Conflicts for python3.8-dev:arm64

Tags: package-management, dpkg, python3, multiarch

I was trying to install python3.8-dev:arm64 with multiarch on 20.04. Howerver, it is getting conflicts with amd64 packages.

Any clues how to resolve this?

```
root@c0fe2d117b18:/workspace# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
arm64

root@c0fe2d117b18:/workspace# apt-cache policy python3.8:arm64
python3.8:arm64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.5-1~20.04
  Version table:
     3.8.5-1~20.04 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com focal-security/main arm64 Packages
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 Packages

root@c0fe2d117b18:/workspace# apt-cache policy python3.8
python3.8:
  Installed: 3.8.5-1~20.04
  Candidate: 3.8.5-1~20.04
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.5-1~20.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Below is the conflict output from aptitude

```
root@c0fe2d117b18:/workspace# aptitude install python3.8-dev:arm64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbz2-1.0:arm64{a} libc6-dev:arm64{a} libcrypt-dev:arm64{a} libdb5.3:arm64{a} libexpat1:arm64{a} libexpat1-dev:arm64{a} libffi7:arm64{a} libgpm2:arm64{a} liblzma5:arm64{a} libmpdec2:arm64{a} libncursesw6:arm64{a}
  libpython3.8:arm64{a} libpython3.8-dev:arm64{a} libpython3.8-minimal:arm64{a} libpython3.8-stdlib:arm64{a} libreadline8:arm64{a} libsqlite3-0:arm64{a} libssl1.1:arm64{a} libtinfo6:arm64{a} libuuid1:arm64{a}
  linux-libc-dev:arm64{a} python3.8:arm64{ab} python3.8-dev:arm64 python3.8-minimal:arm64{ab} uuid-runtime{a} zlib1g:arm64{a} zlib1g-dev:arm64{a}
The following packages will be upgraded:
  liblzma5 libuuid1 zlib1g
3 packages upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 76.0 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8 : Conflicts: python3.8:arm64 but 3.8.5-1~20.04 is to be installed
 python3.8:arm64 : Conflicts: python3.8 but 3.8.5-1~20.04 is installed
 python3.8-minimal : Conflicts: python3.8-minimal:arm64 but 3.8.5-1~20.04 is to be installed
 python3.8-minimal:arm64 : Conflicts: python3.8-minimal but 3.8.5-1~20.04 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:
1)      autodep8 [0.22ubuntu1 (focal, now)]
2)      autopkgtest [5.11ubuntu1 (focal, now)]
3)      lsb-release [11.1.0ubuntu2 (focal, now)]
4)      python3 [3.8.2-0ubuntu2 (focal, now)]
5)      python3-apt [2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (focal-updates, now)]
6)      python3-chardet [3.0.4-4build1 (focal, now)]
7)      python3-debian [0.1.36ubuntu1 (focal, now)]
8)      python3-minimal [3.8.2-0ubuntu2 (focal, now)]
9)      python3-pkg-resources [45.2.0-1 (focal, now)]
10)     python3-six [1.14.0-2 (focal, now)]
11)     python3.8 [3.8.5-1~20.04 (focal-security, focal-updates, now)]
12)     python3.8-minimal [3.8.5-1~20.04 (focal-security, focal-updates, now)]

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
13)     autopkgtest recommends autodep8
14)     libsbuild-perl recommends autopkgtest (>= 4.0.4)
15)     sbuild recommends autopkgtest (>= 4.0.4)
16)     python3-apt recommends lsb-release
17)     python3.8-minimal recommends python3.8



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

Comment: What use could you have for installing `python3.8-dev:arm64` on an `amd64` system?

Comment: @muru It is for cross building some package which has dependency on python3.8-dev.